# C++ idiom for base class abstract methods without dynamic dispatch overhead?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++, is there any way to have an "abstract" base class method (*i.e.*, declared and callable from the base class, but implemented in subclasses) without declaring the method as `virtual`?

This question, of course, only applies to cases where polymorphism isn't needed (pointers/references to base types never used). Consider the following:

```
#define NO_OPT asm volatile ("");  // to prevent some compiler optimization

template<typename DerivedType>
void doSomething(DerivedType& d) { d.foo(); }

namespace test1 {

    struct Base {
        inline void foo()
        {
            // ... do common stuff pre-call ...
            foo_impl();
            // ... do common stuff post-call ...
        }
        virtual void foo_impl() = 0; // the abstract method
    };
    struct D1 : public Base { virtual void foo_impl() final { NO_OPT } };
    struct D2 : public Base { virtual void foo_impl() final { NO_OPT } };

    // Then the usage of D1, D2, ..., DN, could be as follows:

    void go() {

        D1 d1; doSomething(d1);
        D2 d2; doSomething(d2);

        for ( long i=0; i < 5000000000; i++ ) {
            // this loop takes [9] seconds
            doSomething(d2);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that polymorphism is **not** needed in this case, and that there are plenty of optimization opportunities for the compiler.

However, I benchmarked this code in the latest `g++` (4.8.2) and `clang` (3.4) with `-O3` optimizations enabled, including link-time (LTO), and it was significantly slower than the following alternative implementation (using templates instead of virtual method):

```
namespace test2 {

    template<typename DerivedType>
    struct Base : public DerivedType  // inheritance in reverse
    {
        inline void foo()
        {
            // ... do common stuff pre-call ...
            DerivedType::foo_impl();
            // ... do common stuff post-call ...
        }
    };
    struct D1 { void foo_impl() { NO_OPT } };
    struct D2 { void foo_impl() { NO_OPT } };

    void go() {
        Base<D1> d1; doSomething(d1);
        Base<D2> d2; doSomething(d2);

        for ( long i=0; i < 5000000000; i++ ) {
            // this loop takes [3] seconds
            doSomething(d2);
        }
    }
}
```

`g++` and `clang` were remarkably consistent, each compiling optimized code that took 9 seconds to execute the `test1` loop, but only 3 seconds to execute the `test2` loop. So even though the `test1` logic has no need for dynamic dispatch as all calls should be able to be resolved at compile time, it is still significantly slower.

**So to restate my question:** When polymorphism isn't needed, Is there a way to achieve this "abstract method" behavior using the convenient straight-forward class inheritance (like in `test1`), but without the performance penalty of virtual functions (as achieved in `test2`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why should explicitly invoking runtime support for a situation you don't have and don't want to have be considered straightforward?  That'll confuse humans, too. Templates are the perfect tool for this job.

You want a common interface.  Given your example template implementation, you don't even need any obvious relation between the types that have it, just that they do have it.

The classic [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern_) way is

```
template<class d>
struct b { 
    void foo() { bark(); static_cast<d*>(this)->foo_impl(); bite(); }
};

struct d1 : b<d1> { void foo_impl() { fuzzbang("d1"); } };
struct d2 : b<d2> { void foo_impl() { fizzbuzz("d2"); } };
```

which people will have seen before, it's idiomatic as requested, but your

```
class m1 { protected: void foo_impl() { f1("1"); } };
class m2 { protected: void foo_impl() { f2("2"); } };

template<class m>
struct i : private m { void foo() { bark(); m::foo_impl(); bite(); } };
```

has a lot to recommend it too: there's no casting necessary, and the intent is as clear.

---

I don't think you can legitimately compare optimizer results on code with embedded volatile accesses with results on similar code without them.  Try the two implementations in your actual code.  Performance for anything you're doing five billion times is almost certain to be dominated by cache effects not instruction count anyway.

Comment: Your example uses the `CRTP` pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) which is similar to the `test2` example I gave, and does appear to be the best solution to this problem. The `asm volatile` is necessary because, otherwise, the compiler was smart enough (in test2 case, not in test1 case) to optimize away the function call. It emits no instructions, but tells the compiler there are "important side effects" forcing it to make the call. And it seemed to work, as the benchmarks were consistent with the known cost of virtual vs non-virtual dispatch time-cost.

Comment: @etherice: Yes, you asked if there's a simpler way than your test2 that is faster than test1.  CRTP is the answer to that question.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The problem is the answer talks primarily about the `asm volatile` (which was *necessary* for running the benchmarks w/ `-O3` enabled) and fails to specifically mention the `CRTP` pattern. If it were edited to that effect I would accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If a function has a polymorphic value (a reference or pointer to a polymorphic type), and it calls a `virtual` function through that variable, the compiler *must assume* that this could be that class or any class derived from it. And since polymorphism doesn't allow the compiler to know whether there are classes derived from it, it *must* use a virtual dispatch to call the function.

There is only one way to avoid the use of virtual dispatch on calling a virtual function via a polymorphic value: to call the specific type's function *directly*, exactly as you did in your case #2.

Where you put this call is up to you. You could put the call into `foo`, you could have a `derived_foo` alternate function that people use to call the derived-class version, etc. However you want to do it, you must ultimately call the `virtual` function in a different way. Which requires using a different codepath.

It is possible that, if provided with a polymorphic variable of a `final` class, a compiler could optimize all `virtual` calls into that variable into non-virtual dispatches. However, that is not required behavior by the standard. Each compiler may or may not implement that optimization, so unless it becomes widespread, you can't count on it.

This question seems very much like an XY problem. You're trying to solve some problem, and you settled on a base class with a virtual function, with a derived class that you'll always be using. This problem is best solved via [the CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), which doesn't use virtual functions at all.

Comment: That's incorrect... the virtual override is declared as `final` (c++11) which tells the compiler, with absolute certainty, that the virtual function cannot be overridden again (by a subclass of that type) which allows it to bind that call to the `final` override.

Comment: @etherice: Yes, but it doesn't explicitly require the compiler to *not* use virtual dispatch. If you do `ClassName::FunctionName`, the compiler is *explicitly required* by the standard to call that exact function. If `final` is on a virtual function/class, then no derived class will override it/exist, but the compiler is still free to use the virtual dispatch machinery to call that function, since that machinery will *always* point to the same function.

Comment: @etherice: Not as long as you use `virtual` functions (for a reason you haven't explained). You made that an explicit requirement of your question, so we can't really suggest something better. You don't have to do exactly what `test2` did, but someone, somewhere will have to call the derived class function with a qualified name.

Comment: I explained in the comment just posted above why `virtual` is needed in `test1` (so the abstract method dispatches to the implementation in the derived class). However, this does not require **dynamic** dispatch, as proven in `test2` which does the exact same thing without using `virtual`. In other words, the compiler is making me pay for something I'm not using, especially given that the override is `final`. Anyway, I think I will probably accept your answer, especially with the `CRTP` update, which at least provides a name for the pattern used in `test2`.

Comment: @etherice: No, that's *not* the pattern used in `test2`. The CRTP *doesn't use virtual calls*. You are using a bad knock-off of the CRTP, which is why you're getting the performance you are. As stated in the wiki article, "This technique achieves a similar effect to the use of virtual functions, *without the costs*".

Comment: I don't use virtual calls in `test2` at all. You're referring to `test1`. Did you read the entire question?

Comment: @etherice what if some other translation unit has something that derives from `test1::Base`? Also, remember the interactions that virtual has with dynamic libraries loaded at runtime (not in the standard but commonly used). It seems like such a fringe case for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need dynamic polymorphism then do not use keyword `virtual` in your code:

```
#define NO_OPT asm volatile ("");  // to prevent some compiler optimization

template<typename T>
void doSomething(T& d) { d.foo(); }

namespace test1 
{
    struct Base
    {
    protected:
        void prior() {}
        void after() {}
    };

    struct D1
        :public Base 
    { 
        void foo() 
        {
            prior();
            NO_OPT
            after();
        }
    };

    struct D2
        :public Base
    { 
        void foo() 
        {
            prior();
            NO_OPT
            after();
        }
    };

    void go() {

        D1 d1; doSomething(d1);
        D2 d2; doSomething(d2);

        for ( long i=0; i < 5000000000; i++ ) {
            doSomething(d2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the `test2` example I provided in the question (which doesn't use `virtual`, btw) except this doesn't give the `Base` class access to methods in `Derived` through template, and consequently violates the `DRY` (don't repeat yourself) principle as can be seen with each of your derived classes having to repeat the `prior()` and `after()` calls.

Comment: @etherice Yes, CRTP is most natural choice on cases like that. The author of question (you) did not like it for whatever reason so I did suggest alternative without it.

Comment: I was basically using the pattern in `test2` without knowing it was a flavor of CRTP (and that it even had such a name). I never said I didn't like it, I just wanted to know if there was something better and as it turns out there wasn't. I accepted the answer for pointing out that it's similar to an existing pattern (CRTP).